# Twitch API Login - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, authorization, twitch, twitch-api

I'm developing my first App, and I decided to use react native. The API requests I'm currently testing are working fine, but now I want a user to be able to login with the implicit grant flow from Twitch API. I do not have a backend, just my App. I tried to read about deep linking, but I'm not really sure how I redirect Twitch back to my app, because TwitchAPI is only accepting links that start with "HTTPS" as redirect-urls. How can I make Twitch redirect to my app and pass me the right token?

This is the Code I've got so far...

```
var baseURL = 'https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize';
// var redirect_uri = 'https://twitchapps.com/tokengen/'
var redirect_uri = ''
var response_type = 'token';
var scope = 'channel:manage:polls'    

var formattedScope = scope.replace(':','%3A');

var requestUri = baseURL + '?response_type=' + response_type + '&client_id=' + this.clientID + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&scope=' + formattedScope;

Linking.addEventListener('url',this.handleUrl);

await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(requestUri);
```